# Find pairs $(a, b)$ that satisfy $a^{\log_b (a^{-4})} = b^{\log_a (ba^{-3})}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification

**Question:** Find the number of ordered pairs of integers $(a, b)$ with both $a$ and $b$ less than or equal to $2021$,
that satisfy the equation $a^{\log_b(a^{-4})} = b^{\log_a(ba^{-3})}$.

**My work:**

$a^{\log_b(a^{-4})} = b^{\log_a(ba^{-3})} \Longrightarrow a^{\log_b(\frac{1}{a^4})} = b^{\log_a(\frac{b}{a^3})}.$

Hence, using one of the logirathmetic formulas, we can get that $a^{\log_b(\frac{1}{a^4})} = a^{-4(\log_b(a))}$.

Similarily, for $b^{\log_a(\frac{b}{a^3})}$, we can equal this to $b^{(-\frac{1}{3}\log_a(b))}$.

Since $\log_a(b) = \frac{1}{\log_b(a)}$, if we let $\log_b(a) = x$, we get $a^{-4x} = b^{-3x}$.

But, I am stuck on this equation and don't know what to do. I also don't know if I made any mistakes in my steps to get this equation.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit different approach:

Taking $\log _a$ both sides and simplifying

$$ -4\log_ba=(\log_a b^)2-3(\log_a b) $$

Let $x=\log_a b$ and simplifying

$$ x^3-3x^2+4=0 \implies (x-2)(x-2)(x-1)=0  ​$$

So $$ b=a^2,b=a^{-1} $$

Second one is eliminated (Why?)

We know $a,b>1$ (why?)

So you can solve this further

> You will get $\sqrt{2021}-1$

Comment: Thanks Jitendra! I accepted your answer.

Comment: @Iamaperson Good to know this helps you. Thanks